# JBoss ActiveMQ on Red Hat - Unable to access AMQ Web Console

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic, redhat

I have a working ActiveMQ setup on Ubuntu Server. Now I am trying to set up a JBoss-AMQ on Red Hat 6. I am able to run the service,

```
Please wait, JBoss A-MQ is initializing...
100% [========================================================================]

      _ ____                                __  __  ____
     | |  _ \                    /\        |  \/  |/ __ \
     | | |_) | ___  ___ ___     /  \ ______| \  / | |  | |
 _   | |  _ < / _ \/ __/ __|   / /\ \______| |\/| | |  | |
| |__| | |_) | (_) \__ \__ \  / ____ \     | |  | | |__| |
 \____/|____/ \___/|___/___/ /_/    \_\    |_|  |_|\___\_\

  JBoss A-MQ (6.0.0.redhat-024)
  http://www.redhat.com/products/jbossenterprisemiddleware/amq/

Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or 'osgi:shutdown' to shutdown JBoss A-MQ.
```

However, I am unable to access ActiveMQ's web console. I see the port 8161 open using Netstat, I also added the webconsole user:password on the config file on /etc/user.properties and /etc/system.properties. I can't figure out how to access the web console. Does any one know how?

Thanks

Comment: I was able to find this, meaning the web console is indeed running. But again, I am unable to access it.

JBossA-MQ:karaf@root> web:list
   ID   State         Web-State       Level  Web-ContextPath           Name
[ 133] [Active     ] [Deployed   ]  [   60] [/activemqweb            ] mq-web-console (5.8.0.redhat-60024)

Comment: You can find some details in the JBoss A-MQ docs about the web console here: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_A-MQ/6.0/html-single/Managing_and_Monitoring_a_Broker/index.html#FMQAdminWebConsole

Comment: @Johann: did you ever resolve this?  I'm on RHEL 7 with A-MQ 6.1 and am having the exact same problem.