# Red Hat 7 with JBoss A-MQ 6.1: management console is not accessible

Tags: activemq-classic, rhel7

We're having the same problem as this OP:  [JBoss ActiveMQ on Red Hat - Unable to access AMQ Web Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994012/jboss-activemq-on-red-hat-unable-to-access-amq-web-console), however that post doesn't indicate how he solved the problem.

We're trying to evaluate JBoss A-MQ, and have installed RHEL 7 with A-MQ 6.1 according to their [installation guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_A-MQ/6.1/html/Installation_Guide/files/front.html%20Installation%20Guide).  Everything works locally, e.g. the sample producer/consumer tests succeed in the *Verifying the Installation* step.

However, we cannot access the management console, even after configuring the remote user.  We did have to add a JAVA_OPTIONS entry to *setenv* to override the default IPv6 sockets, and netstat shows that the service is now listening on the tcp socket instead of tcp6:

```
File /opt/jboss-a-mq-6.1.0.redhat-379/bin/setenv now contains:
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
export JAVA_OPTS

# netstat -paunt | grep 8181
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8181            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10698/java
```

We can ping the box from other systems, however attempting to open a telnet session on port 8181 times out.  The management console URLs we've tried are:

```
http://172.16.100.110:8181/hawtio
http://172.16.100.110:8181
```

but neither work.  **What are we missing?**

Here are entries from *amq.log* containing *hawt*, which seem like it is starting things up correctly:

```
$ grep hawt amq.log
2014-09-09 11:32:35,778 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | HttpServiceFactoryImpl           | .internal.HttpServiceFactoryImpl   35 | 98 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime - 3.0.6 | Binding bundle: [io.hawt.hawtio-web [146]] to http service
2014-09-09 11:32:35,860 | INFO  | pool-10-thread-1 | ConfigManager                    | io.hawt.system.ConfigManager       32 | 146 - io.hawt.hawtio-web - 1.2.0.redhat-379 | Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2014-09-09 11:32:35,863 | INFO  | pool-10-thread-1 | JmxTreeWatcher                   | io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher         63 | 146 - io.hawt.hawtio-web - 1.2.0.redhat-379 | Welcome to hawtio 1.2-redhat-379 : http://hawt.io/ : Don't cha wish your console was hawt like me? ;-)
2014-09-09 11:32:35,865 | INFO  | pool-10-thread-1 | UploadManager                    | io.hawt.jmx.UploadManager          40 | 146 - io.hawt.hawtio-web - 1.2.0.redhat-379 | Using file upload directory: /opt/jboss-a-mq-6.1.0.redhat-379/data/tmp/uploads
2014-09-09 11:32:35,868 | INFO  | pool-10-thread-1 | AuthenticationFilter             | io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter   84 | 146 - io.hawt.hawtio-web - 1.2.0.redhat-379 | Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "karaf" authorized role: "admin" role principal classes: ""
2014-09-09 11:32:35,965 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | HttpServiceFactoryImpl           | .internal.HttpServiceFactoryImpl   35 | 98 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime - 3.0.6 | Binding bundle: [io.hawt.hawtio-karaf-terminal [148]] to http service
2014-09-09 11:32:35,987 | INFO  | pool-10-thread-2 | ConfigManager                    | io.hawt.system.ConfigManager       32 | 148 - io.hawt.hawtio-karaf-terminal - 1.2.0.redhat-379 | Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2014-09-09 11:32:35,988 | INFO  | pool-10-thread-2 | AuthenticationFilter             | io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter   84 | 148 - io.hawt.hawtio-karaf-terminal - 1.2.0.redhat-379 | Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "karaf" authorized role: "admin" role principal classes: ""
2014-09-09 11:32:35,996 | WARN  | FelixStartLevel  | ConfigFacade                     | io.hawt.config.ConfigFacade        23 | 149 - io.hawt.hawtio-maven-indexer - 1.2.0.redhat-379 | No ConfigFacade constructed yet so using default configuration for now
2014-09-09 11:32:36,015 | INFO  | pool-10-thread-2 | LoginServlet                     | io.hawt.web.LoginServlet           55 | 148 - io.hawt.hawtio-karaf-terminal - 1.2.0.redhat-379 | hawtio login is using default HttpSession timeout
2014-09-09 11:32:36,128 | INFO  | pool-10-thread-1 | hawtio-web - 146}                | lipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog   75 | 90 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.14.v20131031 | jolokia-agent: No access restrictor found at classpath:/jolokia-access.xml, access to all MBeans is allowed
2014-09-09 11:32:36,191 | INFO  | pool-10-thread-1 | LoginServlet                     | io.hawt.web.LoginServlet           55 | 146 - io.hawt.hawtio-web - 1.2.0.redhat-379 | hawtio login is using default HttpSession timeout
2014-09-09 11:32:39,227 | INFO  | de startup timer | MavenIndexerFacade               | maven.indexer.MavenIndexerFacade   98 | 149 - io.hawt.hawtio-maven-indexer - 1.2.0.redhat-379 | Storing maven index files in local directory: /opt/jboss-a-mq-6.1.0.redhat-379/data/mavenIndexer
2014-09-09 11:32:39,621 | INFO  | de startup timer | MavenIndexerFacade               | maven.indexer.MavenIndexerFacade  148 | 149 - io.hawt.hawtio-maven-indexer - 1.2.0.redhat-379 | Updating the maven indices. This may take a while, please be patient...
2014-09-09 11:32:39,852 | INFO  | de startup timer | MavenIndexerFacade               | maven.indexer.MavenIndexerFacade  185 | 149 - io.hawt.hawtio-maven-indexer - 1.2.0.redhat-379 | Completed updating 2 maven indices.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, it was the firewall on the local server.

After spending the day scouring the web for ideas, trying to figure out what was wrong with my configuration, in desperation I finally thought I should try disabling the firewall and see what happens.  So I shut it down with the command:

```
sudo service firewalld stop
```

and suddenly I could access the management console!  I tried the default URL, and it worked:

```
http://172.16.100.110:8181
```

**d'oh!**